# Error in setting up ckanext-wordpresser

Tags: wordpress, ckan

I'm trying to make a wordpress interface for my ckan instance and I found the following plugin:
ckanext-wordpresser

But when I execute the following command:

```
$ pip install -e  git+https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-wordpresser#egg=ckanext-wordpresser
```

I get this error:

> Obtaining ckanext-wordpresser from
>   git+https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-wordpresser#egg=ckanext-wordpresser
>   Updating /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-wordpresser clone
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       running egg_info
>       writing requirements to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/requires.txt
>       writing ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/PKG-INFO
>       writing namespace_packages to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
>       writing top-level names to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/top_level.txt
>       writing dependency_links to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
>       writing entry points to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/entry_points.txt
>       writing pbr to ckanext_wordpresser.egg-info/pbr.json
>       error: Namespace package problem: ckanext.wordpresser is a namespace package, but its
>       **init**.py does not call declare_namespace()! Please fix it.
>       (See the setuptools manual under "Namespace Packages" for details.)
>       "
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-wordpresser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line in setup.py:

```
namespace_packages=['ckanext', 'ckanext.wordpresser'],
```

it will work if it is changed to:

```
namespace_packages=['ckanext'],
```

but I wouldn't do a PR myself since I'm not willing to test it still works (although I think it would). So I suggest you could git clone the repo, make that change and then:

```
pip install -e ../ckanext-wordpresser
```

and it will install ready to try. If it works (and the extension is v. old, so I think a bit of a long-shot) then do create a PR.